# Read contents from xml file and store in an array

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm working with xml for the first time and I have some problems in storing  the contents of the xml file in an array. I'm using libxml2 for parsing the xml file and I'm able to get the data and able to print it. The code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <wchar.h>

wchar_t buffer[7][50]={"\0"};

static void parseDoc(const char *docname) 
{

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    xmlChar *key;
    int i=0;
    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

    if (doc == NULL ) {

    fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
     return;
    }

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
      xmlFreeDoc(doc);
      return;
    }

    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;

    while (cur != NULL) 
    {
        key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        wmemcpy(buffer[i],(wchar_t*)(key),size(key));   /*segmentation fault at this stage*/        
        printf("Content : %s\n", key);
        xmlFree(key);
        i++;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}

int main(void) 
{
   const char *docname="/home/workspace/TestProject/Text.xml;
   parseDoc (docname);
   return (1);
 }
```

The sample xml file is provided below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <story>
  <author>John Fleck</author>
  <datewritten>June 2, 2002</datewritten>
  <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  <headline>This is the headline</headline>
  <para>This is the body text.</para>
 </story>
```

The output of the file contents when printed on the screen were as below

`Content : null`

`Content : John Fleck`

`Content : null`

`Content : June 2, 2002`

`Content : null`

`Content : example keyword`

`Content : null`

`Content : This is the headline`

`Content : null`

`Content : This is the body text.`

I feel that the content of the file being null in few places is causing the problem in copy and hence generating the segmentation fault. Please let me know how to fix the problem and is there an better way to get the thing done. I had  done a similar xml file read using MSXML parser and this is my first time with Linux API's.

**EDIT** The copying part is performed as below but the contents of the wchart array are garbled. Further help would be appreciated.

```
while (cur != NULL) {

    key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
    if(key!=NULL)
    {
        wmemcpy(DiscRead[i],(const wchar_t *)key,sizeof(key));
        i++;
    }

    printf("keyword: %s\n", key);
    xmlFree(key);

    cur = cur->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- You use `wchar_t` for your string array. This isn't appropriate for the UTF-8 encoded strings you'll get from libxml2. You should stick with `xmlChar` or use `char`.
- You use `xmlNodeListGetString` to get the text content of nodes passing `cur->xmlChildrenNode` as node list. The latter will be `NULL` for text nodes, so `xmlNodeListGetString` will return `NULL` as an error condition. You should simply call `xmlNodeGetContent` on the current node but only if it is an element node.
- Using `xmlChildrenNode` as field name is deprecated. You should use `children`.
- The call to `wmemcpy` is dangerous. I'd suggest something safer like `strlcpy`.

Try something like this:

```
char buffer[7][50];

static void parseDoc(const char *docname)
{
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;
    xmlChar *key;
    int i = 0;
    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

    if (doc == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return;
    }

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "empty document\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    for (cur = cur->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
            continue;
        key = xmlNodeGetContent(cur);
        strlcpy(buffer[i], key, 50);
        printf("Content : %s\n", key);
        xmlFree(key);
        i++;
    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}
```

You should also check that `i` doesn't overrun the number of strings in your array.

Comment: strlcpy didnt work and i used memcpy instead , is there a way to convert into wchart array . Any help on that would be great .

Comment: Don't use `memcpy` to copy strings. If you can't use `strlcpy`, try `strncpy` but note that it has some caveats. On Linux, there's generally no need for `wchar_t` since UTF-8 is the preferred character encoding.

Comment: Was using wchart for most of the utf -8 strings in winapi programming.and i'm bit new to these linux api's thanks again for your help .

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` array is not large enough.  Increase buffer size to `buffer[7+3][50]`

```
wchar_t buffer[7][50]={"\0"};
...
while (cur != NULL) {
  wmemcpy(buffer[i],(wchar_t*)(key),size(key));   /*segmentation fault */
  printf("Content : %s\n", key);
  ...
  i++;
}
```

The output is 10 lines of "Content : ...".  Thus `i` incremented form 0 to 9.  But `buffer` may only be indexed 0 to 6.  Indexing 7 and later is undefined behavior and this eventually manifested itself as a segment fault.

Comment: That didnt work , but i modified the logic now i'm able to copy but the conetnts are bit garbled . any idea how to fix the same . i have updated my question .